# How can list the current settings of config variables used by Perl's cpan?

Tags: perl, cpan

Among the many command line options of the `cpan`, which one reports the config variables currently set in `cpan`? I made some changes with `o conf` and want to see if the values are correctly has been set because I don't see their effects.

Comment: Also: `echo o conf | cpan`

Comment: Env vars `PERL_MM_OPT` and `PERL_MB_OPT` may override options passed by `cpan` to the installers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`perldoc cpan`:

> `-J`:  Dump the configuration in the same format that CPAN.pm uses. This is
>           useful for checking the configuration as well as using the dump as a
>           starting point for a new, custom configuration.

You should also be able to get the same (or possibly more) information by running the CPAN shell:

```
 $ perl -MCPAN -e shell

 cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.16)
 Enter 'h' for help.

 cpan[1]> o conf
 $CPAN::Config options from C:\...\.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm:
 ...
 applypatch         []
 auto_commit        [0]
 build_cache        [100]
 build_dir          [C:\...\.cpan\build]
 build_dir_reuse    [0]
 build_requires_install_policy [yes]
 bzip2              [C:\opt\bin\bzip2.EXE]
 ...
```

Comment: It says unknown option! my cpan is 1.9402

Comment: `1.94_02` was released almost exactly **eight** years ago.

Comment: Well I used the default perl on Rocks-6.2! It seems that I have to manually install the latest version.

Comment: @SinanÜnür, RHEL6 comes with 1.9402. It is still relevant.